# How often and when does ASP.NET View gets compiled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've tried to get the answer from MSDN and google but couldn't find it.

I am working on performance optimization of MVC application which requires an understanding of view compilation.

1. When do asp.net MVC views get compiled?
2. Do all views get compiled on application startup or on each request?
3. I assume the compiled views get used until app pool restart.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When does asp.net mvc views get compiled?

The view is compiled when the first request hits and executes the action that returns the view.

> All views gets compiled on application start up or on each request?

No. Not at application start up. Not for each request. If **Request A** return a **View V1**. V1 is compiled. Then If **Request B** arrives and need the same **View V1** then the view is just returned without re-compiling it.

> I assume the compiles views get used until app pool restart?

No, they are compiled only one time and they don't get recompiled when Application Pool restarted.

**Why not pre-compiling your views before publishing your application?**

You can pre-compile your MVC Views when building your application. So you need to unload your MVC project and modify the following XML element

```
<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
```

to this:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

**UPDATES:**

As **Nil Pun** spotted it into comments of my answer, the following [link](http://gunnarpeipman.com/2016/08/asp-net-mvc-precompiling-views/) destroyed the myth about `MvcBuildViews` element in **csproj** file.

So from the author of that article:

> MvcBuildViews is here to make building of views as part of web application building process. It doesn’t generate any output to binaries folder. Views are precompiled during publishing process and precompiling happens only if views are not expected to be modified. It is possible to configure how precompilation is done. This way it is possible to merge binaries of precompiled views to one assembly.

Comment: MvcBuildViews doesn't result on activation of precompiled view see detail here:
http://gunnarpeipman.com/2016/08/asp-net-mvc-precompiling-views/